# How to save recyclerview scroll dx?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using RecyclerView in my project and set layoutManager Vertical.
There are several viewtypes in this recyclerview(tag:ARecyclerView), and most viewTypes contains a recyclerview(tag: BRecyclerView) with horizontal layoutmanger.

but if I scroll horizontal item in BRecyclerView and then scroll vertical of ARecyclerView, at this time, BRecyclerView always be the fist item due to recycler.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> indexmap = new HashMap<>();

public MainAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new AViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    AViewHolder aViewHolder = (AViewHolder) holder;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 400);
    aViewHolder.rootView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    aViewHolder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    aViewHolder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    aViewHolder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new SubAdapter(mContext));
    aViewHolder.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int i = recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 20;
}

private static class AViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public View rootView;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public AViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        rootView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.root_view);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    }
}
}


public class SubAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
public SubAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_sub, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new SubViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SubViewHolder subViewHolder = (SubViewHolder) holder;
    subViewHolder.textView.setText(position + "");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 20;
}

private static class SubViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView textView;

    public SubViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It is because you call setAdapter every time in onBindViewHolder. Try move creating and setting adapter to onCreateViewHolder

Comment: thanks! I have change setAdapter in onCreateViewHolder just as what you say. But, due to it's multiplexing mechanism, for example, when I scroll first item horizontal  and then scroll vertical, new item also appears the same positoin of the first one.  Here is my code https://github.com/simidaxu/VH_RecyclerView_demo.git

Comment: It seems to have to save item scroll position?